# IBM Worklight - How to disable Direct Update?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I would like to disable Direct Update. Is it possible?

With connectOnStartup = false not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to disable Direct Update completely, open a browser and navigate to Worklight Console. There you need to tick the checkbox titled "Lock this version".

[image]

This option means that any future deployments of a .wlapp (of the particular enviornment and its particular version number) *will not update its web resources* on the server, thus not trigger a Direct Update.

See this IBM Worklight user documentation topic: [Locking an application](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/t_locking_an_application.html)

---

`connectOnStartup=false` only means that upon application launch, the app will not try to connect to the Worklight Server; if your application then utilizes `WL.Client.connect` or invokes an adapter procedure, this triggers an init request to the Worklight Server. The application is then connected to the Worklight Server. Now if, for example, the app will return to the foreground (after being in the background), a Direct Update check will be made.

Comment: I am facing similar issue for version 6.2. Is there any problem with the 6.2 version of worklight? I mean "lock this version" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Works fine here; After locking the iPhone v1.0 environment, changing some web resource (for example, adding an alert() in main.js) and trying to build the app, it will fail building - as expected - with this message  in Eclipse: Failed to deploy application 'test' to Worklight Server: Update of application "test" with environment "iphone" and version "1.0" failed 
because it is locked. It can be unlocked using the Worklight console.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In my case, I want to disable the direct update for the app. Everytime I re-build the app and test is on iPad, the app asks me to update. (Which I actually don't want to). I tried locking the version from console.

Comment: You will need to be more forthcoming than that; As I wrote above, I locked the console and as such Direct Update no longer happens. You may be pointing the app to a different server, I don't know. If you continue having issues you should consider opening a PMR and actually explain yourself with full reproduction steps.

Comment: I checked the same build on Andrios Tablet and it's working fine. No automatic update pop up comes in, While for iPad the issue still exist there.