# Disable Direct Update for worklight6.1 development platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Right now i am developing an app on remote DEV server. Every time when i update the code (js,html,css etc) then test on the device locally. There is a popup to force me to update the app. But my app need to connect DEV server for testing some backend feature like login.

DEV server is a remote Websphere running WL6.1 for development purpose. Why i need it because my app connect to some web services like Auth server via internal environment (actually is VPN). And those services i cannot set up easily in local environment. That makes using localhost for development is not really possible.

My problem is feeling the development process not really handy. Every time i change the code and want to run on the devices. I need to upload the .wlapp via console. It takes time! Everyday i change the code thousands time. That's why i need a solution.

And now i am seeking for 2 possible ways:

1. Auto push the .wlapp to remote server when i run and build. Can ANT do that? i read the Doc and find it's a bit of complicated.
2. Disable Direct Update. Actually i do a tricky hack inside worklight.js to override this feature. But i think it is not a good solution. So, is there any server config can switch the that off?

And i read this thread [IBM Worklight - How to disable Direct Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404270/ibm-worklight-how-to-disable-direct-update/22404397#22404397)
Not working.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, things seem to work exactly as they should.

1. You have your local Worklight Development Server (that's the Worklight Studio plug-in you've installed in your Eclipse).
2. You have a remote server - here I am presuming this is actually some application server with Worklight Server deployed on it (that is, not the plug-in, but an actual installation of the server component) as well as your deployed project's .war file.
   If that's not your setup, you need to think again about your 'testing setup'.

> Auto push the .wlapp file to remote server. So the dev server always
>   keep the latest resource. Not to force me "update" the older version
>   on the server.

No. You can't do this. You need to manually build your app with the correct connectivity settings for the remote server via Run As > Build Settings and Remote Target.

In addition to the native project that will now contain these connectivity settings for the actual app, you will also have a .wlapp file in the bin folder. You will need to manually deploy it each time you're changing your app's contents. That's why you do development testing in the local development server... when moving to a remote server, that's for QA/UAT/PROD purposes usually.

> Just disable this annoying feature in DEV environment.
>   You will need to do this in both servers via their respective Worklight Console as described in the question you've linked to, so that once you deploy the .wlapp file, it will not send a Direct Update request.

Instead, you'll need to manually re-install the app each time.

I suspect you didn't do this action on the remote server?
If you did, then you need to explain your setup, as the only thing you've wrote about was its name... "dev".

No. You need to manually deploy the .wlapp to your remote server.

Comment: Can ANT do auto .wlapp push to remote server?