# Wanted to enable the "Directupdate feature in the Worklight application"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have already delivered the 1.0 version of our Worklight application. By mistake we have disabled the Direct update feature by updating the attribute "connectOnStartup = false"

We dont want to redeploy the application to markets (AppStore/GooglePlay) again, but wanted to make our users to utilize the direct update feature. We do have the access to WL server.

Our issue is little different from the one which is already discussed here "[IBM Worklight - How to disable Direct Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404270/ibm-worklight-how-to-disable-direct-update)"

How can we provide the direct update feature to our end users without redeploying the application to AppStore/Googleplay. And just by changing the Webresources of the application.

We are using the adapters in our application but no where we are explicitly calling the "WL.Client.connect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Direct Update feature is **always enabled** by default.
You need to edit your question and explain what it is you've done in your Worklight project.

The feature will **not work** if:

1. You have set `connectOnStartup:false`
2. You are *not* using WL.Client.connect
3. You are *not* invoking adapters
4. You disabled it via the checkbox in Worklight Console

Otherwise, the feature will work, and a check for Direct Update will be performed:

- On application startup
- On return to foreground

Answer (score 1):

The application will need Re-deployment on the App stores.

So the solution to your problem is

> Rebuild the Application with connectOnStartup:true.
> Redeploy the Application on App Stores
>
> Once the users download the updated  application, future updates will go to the users directly.

While rebuilding, make sure that you change the Version of your application within ApplicationDescriptor.

Comment: This is not exactly correct - you should only use connectOnStartup=true if you NEED that; you don't always need that, based on your application.

Comment: yes but if I am not wrong, only connectOnStartup ensures the directUpdate right?

Comment: No, because you can also connect using WL.Client.connect; connectOnStartup means that the framework will auto-connect to the Worklight Server on startup, that's all.

Comment: So if i use "WL.Client.connect" explicitly at the time of initialising the application every time, it checks for "Weather the updates are available or not right?"