# Is it possible to stop automatic updates on worklight server v 6.1

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-server

My drama is to stop my app to update automatically whenever is started. I'm using worklight v6.1 with Android environment. The main goal is not to set **"connectOnStartup:false"**, but only to disable automatic updates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight - How to disable Direct Update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404270/ibm-worklight-how-to-disable-direct-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct update was stopped after migrate to WL 6.2 and using wl_updateRealm to stopped it...

Answer (score 0):

In the Worklight Console you will see a checkbox titled "Lock this version". You need to tick it.

After that, it will not be possible to deploy new .wlapp files, thus no Direct Update will occur.

This question is a duplicate of: [IBM Worklight - How to disable Direct Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404270/ibm-worklight-how-to-disable-direct-update)

Comment: This is not a solution for me. I want to change the apk but not from worklight server but manually. The "Lock Version" means that you cannot upload other version to the wl server. But if i install different apk it connects to the server and see differents and ask me to "Update"

Comment: I'm using HTTPS connection via self signed certificate, and i have problems updating the application. I must add the certificate to the trusted store on all devices, this is not a solution to me, so i decided to add my own update logic, but for that i need to stop the automatic update.

Comment: In Worklight 6.1, the only way to stop Direct Update is as I mentioned. If you want more control over it, you need upgrade to Worklight 6.2 where Direct Update is considered a security test and you can control its logic on your own.

Comment: I've tried some workaround to make https connection between client and ws server to make the update gets failed, and i update the apk and continue working with app but not luck with that...

PS. Lock the version doesn't resolve my problem, this only stop me to upload new .wlapp file, if i choose the apk of the client the worklight see that and updates the apk with the one from the server.

So i can't see a solution to stop direct update on 6.1

Comment: I already provided you with your options; why do you try invalid workarounds?

Comment: My case is that i want to use https via self signed certificate, and i made it but the only problem is the update gets failed via self signed certificate.
And the only solution is to add certificate in trusted credentials store on the devices, that is not a solution to me, because of that i tried different things to pass this and with no luck, the only solution that i found is to upgrade to 6.2 made https, disable the automatic update and add my logic for update via http.